# Functions for these options (Python)

Tags: python

How can i make use of functions in this case.

**what i'm trying to do is when**

**1-will allow the user to input a number to save**

**2-will allow the user to reduce the saved number**

**3- will make the user view the saved number**

**This is my current code:**

```
print '1. Add \n2. Remove \n3. View'

x = raw_input('ur choice:')
```

**when '1' is entered:**

```
if x == '1':
    print 'you have:'
    add = raw_input('how many do you want to add:')
    print '1. Add \n2. Remove \n3. View'
```

**if '2' is entered:**

```
if x == '2':
    print 'you have:'
    remove = raw_input ('How many do you want to remove:')

    print '1. Add \n2. Remove \n3. View'
```

**and if 3 is entered:**

```
if x == '3':
    print 'Total:'
```

Comment: What are you trying to achieve by putting this code into functions, you haven't said if it already works or not, please make question clear.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know what exactly are you expecting, but at least you could move the code into functions:

```
def add:
    print 'you have:'
    add = raw_input('how many do you want to add:')
    prompt()

def remove:
    print 'you have:'
    remove = raw_input ('How many do you want to remove:')
    prompt()

def total:
    print 'Total:'

def prompt:
    print '1. Add \n2. Remove \n3. View'

x = raw_input('ur choice:')
if x == '1':
    add()
elif x == '2':
    remove()
else:
    total()
```

Comment: Consider putting the functions in a dictionary to remove the `if: elif:`.

Comment: what i'm trying to do is when 1-will allow the user to input a number to save 2-will allow the user to delete or reduce the saved number 3- will make the user view the saved number